# Не передаётся значение ключа в форме

Tags: php, html, form, telegram

при отправке формы, в телеграм приходит только ключ, значение где-то теряется, хотя на самом сайте уходит и ключ и значение

```
<div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
    <form action="/telegram.php" method="POST" class="form">
      <div class="row col-12">
        <div class="col-6">
          <input required type="text" name="Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <input required type="text" name="Email" class="form-control mx-4" placeholder="Your Email">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 my-5">
        <input required type="text" name="Title" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Title">
      </div>
      <div class="form-floating">
        <textarea required class="form-control text_area" placeholder="Your Comments" id="floatingTextarea2" style="height: 100px"></textarea>
        <label for="floatingTextarea2">Your Comments</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-3 btn-send-form p-3">SEND MESSAGE</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

```
<?php
 
//Переменная $name,$phone, $mail получает данные при помощи метода POST из формы
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$title = $_POST['Title'];
 
//в переменную $token нужно вставить токен, который нам прислал @botFather
$token = "1509208531:AAGtyzlfLldE1OTEJtggnyTv3N3zjHTw_7A";
 
//нужна вставить chat_id 
$chat_id = "-496705444";
 
//Далее создаем переменную, в которую помещаем PHP массив
$arr = array(
  'Username: ' => $name,
  'Email: ' => $email,
  'Title: ' => $title
);
 
//При помощи цикла перебираем массив и помещаем переменную $txt текст из массива $arr
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
};
 
//Осуществляется отправка данных в переменной $sendToTelegram
$sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");
 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверил на своем боте ваш скрипт, все работает. Но поля пустые, так что нужно смотреть почему они не приходят, возможно в Post запросе поля отправляются в нижнем регистре.

```
$name = 'Name';
$email = 'Email';
$title = 'Title';
```

[image: screen]

**Это не верные предположения:**

мне кажется тут ошибка формирования html (`'%0A'` - такого в нем не бывает)
попробуйте так:

```
$txt = "<pre>";
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b>".$value."\n";
};
$txt .= "</pre>";
$txt = urlencode($txt);
```

тут аналог на js (увы php тут не запустишь)

```js
const arr = { 
  Username: "Иван",
  Email: "ivan@gmail.com",
  Title: "Заголовок"
}

let $txt;
$txt = "<pre>";
Object.entries(arr).forEach(entry => {
  const [$key, $value] = entry;
  $txt += "<b>"+$key+"</b>"+":"+"&nbsp"+$value+"\n";
})
$txt += "</pre>";

document.querySelector('#out').innerHTML =$txt;
document.write(encodeURI($txt))
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Теперь вообще не отправляется

Comment: Попробуйте проверить $txt там должен быть валидный html правда в телеграме он очень ограничен, но брейк там вроде бы был

Comment: Я пересмотрел там есть тег <pre> его и можно использовать поправлю ответ.

Comment: И еще я вспомнил возможно нужно url энкодер (поправлю) я просто не использовал ботов гет запросами, обычно через библиотеки

Comment: К сожалению значение так же не отправляется, но за помощь спасибо

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое

Comment: И не забудьте перегенерить токен)

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое)